# How can I debug HiDpi Wayland issues such as blurry fonts on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: display-resolution, 17.10, wayland

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 17.04 running nicely with Wayland on my Macbook Pro 13" (Retina) to Ubuntu 17.10.

After the upgrade, the fonts in the top bar and windows bar look very blurry. In addition, the hidpi setting in many applications e.g. firefox is incorrect. Please observe examples at [Blurry font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXEqt.png) and [Firefox incorrect hidpi setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywf3z.png)

These problems don't occur when logging in with the X-Server.

How can I debug this problem?

Are there any resources that could help me troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: This will get deleted shortly as its not a question but a complain / rant. But I feel you pain. Consider filing a bug report but be aware that Ubuntu / Gnome is aware of that problem. HiDPI scaling / fractional scaling on Wayland is actively been worked on

Comment: I apologize. It was not meant as a rant. Rather, I'm interested in understanding how to debug this problem and where I can find resources that help me with that. I've edited the question to reflect that.